# How to save commands typed in the immediate window in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, immediate-window

If I have a couple of commands needed to debug something in the **Immediate Window** of Visual Studio I copy out line-by-line into a textfile. For the next debug-session line-by-line has to be pasted back into the immediate window.

If I try to copy+paste all commands at the same time, the immediate window removes all line endings. Therefore all commands are on a single line and executing it, the following message is displayed in the immediate window: `End of expression expected`

So **my question** is: Is there any way to make the described easier?

Comment: How about not using the Immediate Window for repeated ad-hoc debugging, but putting the code in a unit test method?

Comment: @CodeCaster Unfortunately I can't use unit-tests.

Comment: Maybe it would be worth of taking a bit time once in thinking about how to make it unit testable instead of taking the time multiple times when ever your debugging. But thats just my opinion

Comment: @Dom84 Generally you are right. But in this case there is no way :(